# Android: Interface inheritance in generic types

Tags: java

I need to create Database object for different interfaces, inherited from MyInterface, but Java supposes that "Interface" is a Class, then I get compilation error in declaration "<E extends RoomDatabase & Interface>" of create() method. What is correct solution?

```
public interface MyInterface {
}

public interface DbDictionaries extends MyInterface {
}

public interface DBDocuments extends MyInterface {
}

@Database(entities = {}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class DbDictionaries_v1 extends RoomDatabase implements DbDictionaries {
}

@Database(entities = {}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class DBDocuments_v1 extends RoomDatabase implements DBDocuments {
}

public class Database<Interface extends MyInterface> {
    private final WeakReference<Context> context;
    private Interface instance = null;

    public Database(Context context) {
        this.context = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
    }
    
    /* ERROR: unexpected type, required: class, found: type parameter Interface */
    public <E extends RoomDatabase & Interface> void create(@NonNull Class<E> version, @NonNull String name) {
        instance = (Interface)androidx.room.Room.databaseBuilder(context.get(), version, name)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }

    public Interface db() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

It is possible to replace declaration to "<E extends RoomDatabase & MyInterface>", but it leads to warning: "unchecked typecast", because one can write:

```
Database<DbDictionaries> dictionaries = new Database<DbDictionaries>(this);
```

but:

```
dictionaries.create(DBDocuments_v1.class, "Dictionaries_db");
```

-- which is incorrect, because DBDocuments does not extends DbDictionaries interface.

**(updated)**

After all, working code is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Because "<E extends RoomDatabase & DbInterface>" does not allowed in java
public boolean create(@NonNull Class<? extends DbInterface> version, @NonNull String name) {
    try {
        close();
        instance = (DbInterface)androidx.room.Room.databaseBuilder(
                /* Typecast here is very important thing */
                context.get(), version.asSubclass(BaseClass.class), name)
                .allowMainThreadQueries().enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()
                .addMigrations(migrations)
                .build();
        filename = name;
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, `Interface` (note that generic types normally are named using single letters to prevent misunderstandings) could be an interface or a class and thus the compiler complains. If `RoomDatabase` is an interface then just swap it to `Interface & RoomDatabase` but assuming it is a concrete class the compiler won't let you do that because multiple inheritance isn't allowed (e.g. no class could extend `RoomDatabase` and whatever concrete class _could_ be passed as `Interface`).

Comment: Hello there! Looks like this is your first question. In the future, make sure you specify what programming language you're using, on which platform and what library this is related to. The more information you give, the best we'll be able to help you. If I had to guess, I'd say that you want an answer in Java, regarding an android app using the Room library. If that's correct, make sure to edit your post and add this info. Good luck stackoverflowing!

Comment: @TouficBatache i don't know who added the tags, but looking at the code, it's clearly Java, there's no need even to specify it, no question about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a little layer class which extends `Roomdatabase` and implements `MyInterface`

```
public abstract class MyRoomDatabase extends RoomDataBase implements MyInterface {
```

And change your others class :

```
public abstract class DbDictionaries_v1 extends MyRoomDatabase implements DbDictionaries {
```

So if you have the condition `<E extends MyRoomDatabase>`, for sure it implements `MyInterface`

---

But to resolve your problem, you have to remove the `E` and replace it with a `?` in your `create` method.

```
public void create(@NonNull Class<? extends Interface> version, @NonNull String name) {
```

With :

```
public abstract class DbDictionaries_v2 extends RoomDatabase implements DbDictionaries {
```

You can do do this :

```
    Database<DbDictionaries> dictionariesv1 = new Database(new Context());
    dictionariesv1.create(Database.DbDictionaries_v1.class, "Dictionaries_db");
    dictionariesv1.db(); // return a DbDictionaries class
    
    Database<DbDictionaries> dictionariesv2 = new Database(new Context());
    dictionariesv2.create(Database.DbDictionaries_v2.class, "Dictionaries_db");
    dictionariesv2.db(); // return a DbDictionaries class

    Database<DbDictionaries> documentv1 = new Database(new Context());
    // Compilation error here 
    documentv1.create(Database.DBDocuments_v1.class, "Dictionaries_db");
    documentv1.db();
```

*Sorry I don't have Android code, I added an empty class Context for code compilation*